# How to check if a nested member exists Rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have a JSON File like this

```
{
    "Person":[
        {
            "name":"Frank",
            "age":69,
            "amount_of_jobs":9,
            "years_worked":6,
            "unemployed":true,
            "job_seeking":false
        },
        {
            "name":"Tom",
            "age":23,
            "amount_of_jobs":2,
            "years_worked":6,
            "unemployed":false,
            "job_seeking":false
        },
        {
            "name":"Mike",
            "age":31,
            "amount_of_jobs":5,
            "years_worked":12,
            "unemployed":false,
            "job_seeking":false
        },
        {
            "name":"Herb",
            "age":45,
            "amount_of_jobs":7,
            "years_worked":29,
            "unemployed":false,
            "job_seeking":true
        }
    ],
    "Companies":[
        {
            "name":"Slave Inc"
        },
        {
            "name":"Some LLC"
        },
        {
            "name":"Other PTY LTD"
        },
        {
            "name":"A company"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I would like to check if the right keys are in the file.

What I have managed is to check if `Person` and `Companies` exists with this code snippet

```cpp
if (!document.HasMember("Person") || (!document.HasMember("Companies")))
{
    std::cout << "KEY NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
    file.close();
    return false;
}
else
{      
    std::cout << "ALL GOOD" << std::endl;
}
```

But when I try to check if `name` or `years_worked` (which are nested members) exists it does not work.

I've tried:

```cpp
if (!document.HasMember("name") || (!document.HasMember("years_worked")))
{
    std::cout << "KEY NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
    file.close();
    return false;
}
else
{      
    std::cout << "ALL GOOD" << std::endl;
}
```

and

```cpp
if (!document["Person"].HasMember("name") || (!document["Person"].HasMember("years_worked")))
{
    std::cout << "KEY NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
    file.close();
    return false;
}
else
{      
    std::cout << "ALL GOOD" << std::endl;
}
```

and all I get is:

> Assertion failed: (IsObject())

How could I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`Person` is an array so you should access it like an array i.e. by an index.

Example:

```cpp
document["Person"][0].HasMember("name")
```

The same goes for `Companies`.